# Good Mercurial repository viewer for Mac

Tags: macos, version-control, mercurial, dvcs

Is there a good, native Mac tool to view Mercurial repositories, similar to gitnub for Git?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I know it's pretty old question, however just for sake of completeness, I think it is still worth to mention here the newest kid on the block called [Murky](http://bitbucket.org/snej/murky/wiki/Home).

Comment: yes, murky looks fine, but there is no tut at all :/ it would be great to have a quick start video tut for that. I'm having difficulties as a new source control user :/

Comment: There is now a new newest kid on the block called MacHg: http://jasonfharris.com/machg/ :-) It supports big repositories and looks very smooth.

Comment: Yes Murky is really slow when scrolling through the reposity history.

Comment: Murky has not had any development since 2010. I would recommend looking at another option.

Comment: Doesn't work with MacOS Sierra?

Answer (score 23):

Try the newly released [**MacHg**](http://jasonfharris.com/machg/). It uses the native GUI toolkit for Mac and comes with its own bundled version of Mercurial.

[image: State after a merge in MacHg]

There are [many more screenshots](http://jasonfharris.com/machg/sceenshots/sceenshots.html) available.

Comment: Is there a way to integrate the viewer into the ~/.hgrc? So "hg view" will start the viewer?

Comment: fyi: your image is now a broken link.

Comment: @math: the idea is that you use MacHg for most or all of your Mercurial tasks, but if you want, then you can use a [shell alias](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#alias) to make `hg view` launch MacHg.

Comment: @PaulNathan: The link somehow got fixed, but I've now replaced it with a link to imgur.com. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: This has not had any development done since 2014. I would recommend another choice. SourceTree is a good choice. MacHg would not run Mac OS Sierra (10.12.1).

Answer (score 13):

I just released a new tool, [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com) which is native Mac OS X and lets you work with both Mercurial and Git repositories in one application.
[image]

Comment: SourceTree is *excellent* - I pray that one of these days such a client will be available on Windows to replace TortoiseHg - not that TortoiseHg is terrible, but I like the "standalone-ness" of SourceTree and that It Just Works.

Comment: @Brandon: Shelving in SourceTree is very bad. Shelves all or nothing.

Comment: Its beautiful, fast, and works flawlessly on Mac. (Env: MacOS Sierra)

Answer (score 9):

A few months back, Dustin Sallings wrote a [fork](http://github.com/dustin/gitnub/wikis) of GitNub that uses Mercurial.  It's Leopard-only, but lovely.

On Tiger, the "view" exension mentioned in the other comments works okay, as does [hgview](http://www.logilab.org/project/hgview).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the one "built in", [`hg view`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/index.cgi/HgkExtension). You'll need `TCL` installed though.

> From the documentation:
>
> > The hgk Tcl script is a direct port of the gitk tool used with git. The hgk.py extension allows hgk to interact with mercurial in a git-like manner.

*edit* @ [Matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30903/good-mercurial-repository-viewer-for-mac#31434): yeah, that's why I linked to the documentation that explains it. You need to enable it in your .hgrc (like the `fetch` command), and TCL --as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

> hg: unknown command 'view'

(Maybe I need to install something - but it's not native, nonetheless).

There is one "native" application out there, but it's not especially user-friendly.  In fact, I'd go as far as saying that it's harder to use than the command line.

There was some talk a year or so ago about a version of SCPlugin, which puts badges on icons in the Finder that are under SVN control, and gives you a contextual menu (very much like TortoiseSVN on windows), but that seems to have collapsed.

I have been planning to create a mercurial "clone" of Versions (I asked them if they would consider doing a version of it for DVCS, and they said no).